# Show/hide info using slideToggle on button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

**Objective** Inserting name(input-text) and info(textarea-contains multiple lines) into the database, and after submission of the form, at the same page, 2 columns are for displaying the same data in columns, name & info, but under info column. I have made buttons for each row in front of the names, which is used as `slideToggle` for showing/hiding which contains the data retrieved from the 'info' column

**Problem** - when I am clicking the button of 1st row, instead of displaying the info related to 1st entry only, it is sliding and showing all info(s) related to all entries at only click.

*others - one more input has been added to the form but as hidden used for id(auto increment)

[image: screenshot with the toggle problem]

```html
----index.php-----

<?php  include('php_code.php'); ?>
<?php 
 if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
  $id = $_GET['edit'];
  $update = true;
  $record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM records WHERE id=$id");

  if (count($record) == 1 ) {
   $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
   $name = $n['name'];
   $acc = $n['acc_no'];
   $info = $n['info'];
  }
 }
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSK</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('form').hide();
 $('p').hide();
 $('#sp').hide();
    $("#inf").click(function(){
     $("p").slideToggle();
     $('#sp').slideToggle();
    });
$("#fo").click(function(){
        $("form").slideToggle();
      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  <?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
  <div class="msg">
  <?php 
   echo $_SESSION['message']; 
   unset($_SESSION['message']);
  ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif ?>

  <?php $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM records"); ?>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Account No</th>
   <th>Info</th>
   <th colspan="2">Action</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['acc_no']; ?></td>
   <td><button id="inf" onclick="myFunction()">show</button></td>
   <td>
    <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Edit</a>
   </td>
   <td>
    <a href="php_code.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="del_btn">Delete</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr  id="sp"> <td colspan="4"><p> <?php echo $row['info']; ?> </p></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?> 
</table>
<div id="fotable" align="center">
<button id="fo">Add New/Edit</button> 
</div>

 <form method="post" action="php_code.php" >
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

  <div class="input-group">
   <label>Name</label>
   <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
   <label>Account No</label>
   <input type="text" name="acc" value="<?php echo $acc; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
      <label for="info">Info</label>

      <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" name="info" id="info"><?php echo $row['info']; ?></textarea>

    </div>
  <div class="input-group">
   <?php if ($update == true): ?>
 <button class="btn" type="submit" name="update" style="background: #556B2F;" >update</button>
<?php else: ?>
 <button class="btn" type="submit" name="save" >Add Account</button>
<?php endif ?>
  </div>
 </form>
</div><!-- left closed -->
<div class="right">

hello



</div> <!-- right closed -->
</div> <!-- container closed -->
</body>
</html>

---php_code.php-----

<?php 
 session_start();
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'jskrecords');
 

 // initialize variables
 $name = "";
 $acc = "";
 $info = "";
 $id = 0;
 $update = false;

 if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $acc = $_POST['acc'];
  $info = $_POST['info'];

  mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO records (name, acc_no, info) VALUES ('$name', '$acc', '$info')"); 
  $_SESSION['message'] = "Account saved"; 
  header('location: index.php');
 }
 if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $acc = $_POST['acc'];
 $info = $_POST['info'];

 mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE records SET name='$name',acc_no='$acc',info='$info' WHERE id=$id");
 $_SESSION['message'] = "Account updated!"; 
 header('location: index.php');
}
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
 $id = $_GET['del'];
 mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM records WHERE id=$id");
 $_SESSION['message'] = "ACC deleted!"; 
 header('location: index.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concept:

If you are creating multiple form from same mysql table using php script, You need to give each form a unique id.
e.g.

```
<form method="post" action="php_code.php" id="form<?= $id ?>">
```

Then add data-target="#form" to button with class 'inf'. It will store id of form.

```
<button class="inf" data-target="#form<?= $id ?>">show</button>
```

When button is clicked we know which form to open from data-target.

```
<script>
$('.container').on('click','button.inf',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var formid=$(this).attr('data-target');  //get value of data-target attribute 
       //...proceed to play toggle with this form 'formid'
```

Comment: By using slideToggle with formid, it is toggling the form with input fields. But I want that if I click show button of the 1st row so it shows the <p> info which is stored in DB of 1st entry only, same for each and every entry individually. Please help it out